# Windows 10 in VirtualBox: fails after update

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-update

ALL,

I have a Windows 10 VirtualBox VM.

Tonight it picked up some updates and after reboot it won't start.

```
Something went wrong
    But you can try again

       OUTRO
```

Trying again doesn't help.

Is there anything I can do?

I will turn off automatic updates after that, because it failed during the install as well.

TIA!!

As requested here is the screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide the Windows Update logs and [edit] your question to include that vital information.  Where is this error displayed?

Comment: Do you have the Virtual Box Guest Additions installed?  If not, install them, as it may help.

Comment: @Ramhound, I just presumed it is after update. Also, the machine is not booted up - it is stuck during reboot. So I can't give you the log. And I don't understand the last question - error is displayed on the monitor, where else?

Comment: @Keltari, they are installed.

Comment: This a BSOD? I am not aware of any Windows error message that contains the word “OUTRO”.  Screenshot of the error message might help.

Comment: @Ramhound, screenshot added. As you can see it is not BSOD. However it is inside VM, so maybe it is...

Comment: That’s an error during the first phases after Windows is installed (OOBE) and I suspect has to do with the fact the VM doesn’t have internet capability.  If you hit “try again” what happens?

Comment: @Ramhound, well everything is installed and worked correctly. So it is not the install thing. Hitting `Try Again` brings me back to exactly the same screen. And the VM is definitely have Internet access. So how can I get out of this loop?

Comment: You probably have to boot into WinRE and revert the pending updates.  I am guessing you don’t have a snapshot from before the update was installed?

Comment: @Ramhound, no I don't. Didn't expect this to happen. Can you give an instructions on how to do that? Now what is the best way to keep Internet open (I will need to push/pull to/from GitHub) or clip the updates (which is not a good idea from Windows POV). So what are the best solution here?

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+F4?  Cause your installation also isn’t activated

Comment: @Ramhound, nothing happens

Comment: @Ramhound, so I got curious and cold rebooted the VM (shut it down and then booted it up). Surprisingly enough the machine booted up successfully. While I am interested for the cause the issue itself is resolved. Thank you.